# Some functions from marklogic v7 are missing in marklogic 10

Tags: marklogic

I have installed version 10.0-6.4 and I am running some tests against it.  We have baseline tests results again old v 7.0.  I am finding out that several functions are missing.

For example `date()` and `datetime()`.
For example on v7 I can run this query `SELECT date()`, but on v10 it produces error:

> [SQL] XDMP-UNDFUN: (err:XPST0017) Undefined function date().

There are several "missing" functions as compared to v7, so I am wondering if maybe I need to install some additional packages on my v10 or something like that.  Anyone help help?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything called out in [Known Incompatibilities](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/relnotes/chap4#chapter) in the release notes mentioning `date()`, but it is possible that some functions happened to work previously in SQL and are no longer available.

The list of currently supported SQL functions are provided:
https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/sql/SQLqueries#id_97459

Instead of `date()` or `dateTime()`, you could use `curdate()`

```
SELECT curdate();
```

or `curtime()`

```
SELECT curtime();
```

and you can also [use built-in functions](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/sql/SQLqueries#id_13409), such as `fn:current-date()`

```
SELECT fn_current_date();
```

or `fn:current-dateTime()`

```
SELECT fn_current_datetime();
```